# Activity Indicator not showing on view controller

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to figure out why my activity indicator is not showing on my view controller, here is my code below

```
var activityIN : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        activityIN.center = self.view.center
        activityIN.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIN.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        activityIN.startAnimating()
```

Comment: So the activity indicator is not showing up on the view controller when you run the project?

Comment: How have you added it to the view?

Comment: Looking at your code above, I cannot see where you have added your activity indicator to the view. Have you tried adding it to the view?

Comment: Yes I have added it to the view

Comment: Have you tried this 'view.addSubview(activityIN)' ?

Comment: @JohnGool Yes I have tried that, but it still does not appear

Comment: Okay. So I don't understand what is the problem. Can you show some more code please?

Comment: What code do you want to see?

Comment: @TimSmith Just to make sure, have you definitely added the activity indicator to the view controller? for example using, view.addSubview(activiyIN)  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this , see the last line you have forget that

```
var activityIN : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(100 ,200, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
activityIN.center = self.view.center
activityIN.hidesWhenStopped = true
activityIN.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
activityIN.startAnimating()
self.view.addSubview(activityIN)
```

Comment: @TimSmith I said this to you twice in the comments. How did you not understand?